# Don't understand 'complete-items' in the vim help files

Tags: vim, omnicomplete

I am looking at the vim help files and looking for a variable on the linux version that is like `v:completed_item` from cygwin. `v:completed_item` is a:

> Dictionary containing the complete-items for the most recently completed word after CompleteDone.  The Dictionary is empty if the completion failed.

I am looking for the same thing for Linux but I cannot find it and the closes thing I can find in the ins-completion help file is `complete-item` but nothing on how to use it anyone know how to use it? And if it will be the same as the `completed_item` from the cygwin version?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The presence of a feature doesn't depend on the platform, it depends on the build type, version number, and patch-level.

If you want feature parity between two environments, you *rather obviously* must install the same build type and version number (including patches) on both environments.

FYI, that variable was added in patch 7.4.774.